# Flink: Run sinks separately

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am consuming data from `Kafka` and I need to write the stream to both my local file and a port listened by `Flume`

The code can run as expected as follows:

```
streamSource.writeToSocket("192.168.95.11", 9158, new SimpleStringSchema());
streamSource.writeAsText("/tmp/flink_output.txt").setParallelism(1);
```

However, when the port is closed, the whole flink task stops. Is there any way to make them run separately: when port is closed, `writeToSocket` keeps retring while `writeAsText` runs as usual?

Answer (score 0):

For that to happen, where the same source is used for both, then the data read from the source that should have been written to the socket would have to either be buffered somewhere capable of absorbing an unbounded amount of data -- or that data would have to be dropped.

Or you could separate the two pipelines and make them completely independent of one another. This could be done by having two separate jobs, or one job with fully decoupled pipelines, in which case a failure of one will not restart the other. See [failover strategies from the Flink 1.9 release notes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/release-notes/flink-1.9.html#failover-strategies) and [pipelined region failover strategy](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/task_failure_recovery.html#restart-pipelined-region-failover-strategy).

You would need to do something like this:

```
source1.writeToSocket(...)
source2.writeAsText(...)
```

Here source1 and source2 are two separate kafka consumers, reading independently from the same topic(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply man. However I am only allowed to use one Kafka consumer id, it seems I cannot create 2 sources...